# ADB does not install any APK

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

This is an old phone LG L90 with Android 5.0.2 Lollipop (it does not support any newer version).

ADB does not install any APK, like literally any, old or new, any app, downloaded from anywhere on the internet. E.g. Google Play will fail installing Google Drive latest version assuming they dropped support for Lollipop.

So e.g. you can download older versions from [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/drive/drive-2-18-252-01-release/google-drive-2-18-252-01-30-android-apk-download/#variants) (versions tthat support Android 5+ and I tried most of them).

E.g. you can still install many apps via Google Play successfully, but if you download that same APK file with same version and try to install it via ADB it fails?

Command used is `adb install filename.apk`

Error `Invalid APK file`

- Debugging via USB is enabled
- Play Protect disabled
- Device is not rooted

Comment: Can you download [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.iamtrk.androidexplorer/) (or any app that supports your Android) from F-Droid (it is a Free/libre app repository) and install it using adb? Do you still get an error? Can you try installing it using a file manager app? Do you also fail to install using a file manager app?

Comment: @Firelord hi, it did install via File Manager, but I get same error via ADB https://i.imgur.com/MqL5phr.png

Comment: Usually you execute `adb install` without executing `adb shell` before. Therefore on your PC just execute `adb install ...` and afterwards (or in a second terminal) `adb logcat`. The logcat output should include the real error/exception what is going wrong.

Comment: @Robert Hi, thank you for your help, it does attempt installing apps now and it did succeed, but I still can't install Google Drive. I get error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]`, but there is no existing installation, or at least I cannot find it listed with `pm list packages`. List of all packages https://pastebin.com/yrA3BaYW

Comment: Most likely Google Drive is installed as system app on your device. You can try to install the app as update via `adb install -r ...`. But you should really go back to the app Firelord has linked. Don't start with the hardest enemy, start with the most easy one...

Comment: Android Explorer installed successfully and some others. But I really just want to have Google Drive installed and running. I guess this is going off topic.

Comment: The `-r` did install Google Drive, but no icon available to start the app and in Apps settings it says it is running?

Comment: Can you respond with Answer so I can close this thread, please? I will start new one for Google Drive issue.